# Elixir Functions Immutable Data?

Tags: elixir, immutability

It is my understand that as a Functional Programming (FP) language, input data (args) are immutable. They provide the function with data, which is then copied and the copy is what is mutated (changed). The final version of that data is what is passed back as the Result (return value).

I am working in the iex and:

```
iex(1)> x = [4,5,6]
[4, 5, 6]
iex(2)> x = M.immute_stuff(x)
[4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]
iex(3)> x
[4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]
iex(4)>
```

Where:

```
Defmodule M do

  def immute_stuff(x_arg) do
    x_arg = x_arg ++ [1,2,3]
    IO.inspect x_arg
  end

end
```

From what I can see, the value of `x` is very mutable.

What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Does this mean that immutability of input argument data is actually my responsibility and not enforced by the compiler or the BEAM?

Comment: A recent example on StackOverflow showing the difference in practice https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73519715/how-do-variables-work-with-recursion-in-elixir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example code was not a mutation, but a rebind or shadow.

It is essentially equivalent to this code:

```elixir
defmodule M do
  def immute_stuff(x_arg) do
    x_arg2 = x_arg ++ [1,2,3]
    IO.inspect x_arg2
  end
end
```

Notice the `2` on the "new" variable.

Now, why does this matter, and how is it different to mutating a value?

Let's look at some javascript first, to understand how a language allowing mutation would behave:

```js
myInnerObj = {}
myObj = { content: myInnerObj }
console.log(myObj)
// prints "{ content: {} }"
myInnerObj["type"] = "bag"
console.log(myObj)
// prints "{ content: { type: 'bag' } }"
```

Now let's look at what the "same" elixir code would do:

```elixir
my_inner_map = %{}
my_map = %{ content: my_inner_map }
IO.inspect my_map
# prints "%{content: %{}}"
my_inner_map = Map.put(my_inner_map, :type, "bag")
IO.inspect my_map
# prints "%{content: %{}}"
```

When we change the contents of the `my_inner_map`, it is not a mutation, but a new map being created and bound to that variable name from that point onwards. What that effectively means is that changing one variable will NEVER change the value stored in other variables, like what happens in the javascript example. Every change to variable contents must be explicit, since the contents cannot be mutated, only rebound.

Comment: Thank you for a thoughtful answer in addition to the other response answer (above)! :-)

From where I sit, true immutable input data would throw an exception on rebinding on the inside of a function. Doesn't this capacity for rebinding (happens in every language I am aware of) of input arguments inside a function break the immutable expectation? Now—that said—I do "get" that by changing the variable name, I am skirting the rebinding. That's obvious. However—I expected the compiler to complain about the rebinding. And I suppose that is my real point. Not that I do not get rebinding. :-)

Comment: BTW—I watched a video overview of FP yesterday that made me aware of FP languages view on immutability of f(x), where an ingenious copy method in a tree is applied so that huge data sets are not copied wholesale in memory. Memalloc is extremely expensive. So, I see the "trick", which is really very cool and removes a complaint against FP in a big way. Thanks again for your time and answer! :-)

Comment: I think this [post](https://dashbit.co/blog/comparing-elixir-and-erlang-variables) from Jose Valim, creator of Elixir, explains the decision behind allowing variable re-binding. TLDR: it ends up with code like `t1 = foo(t); t2 = bar(t1); ...` which is a bit tedious to write, but arguably also quite hard to refactor (e.g. adding a step in the middle etc). And this is Robert Virding's (a creator of Erlang) [take on it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35315375/13979518).

Comment: Was about to link that post from Valim! It explains pretty well why the decision was made and the tradeoffs involved.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, you didn't mutate `x`, you just re-assigned it when doing

```elixir
x = M.immute_stuff(x)
```

If you replace it with just

```elixir
M.immute_stuff(x)
```

you'll see that `x` stayed unchanged.

In the same way that strings are immutable in most programming languages, yet if you do:

```javascript
s = s + "!"
```

(in Javascript or Python for example), the variable `s` is going to be re-assigned to the result of appending `"!"` to `s`, yet the append operation itself doesn't mutate `s`.

Comment: However, note that I am rebinding x from within the `def` function. I do see what you mean about the `x` variable being rebound with the results of the function call. That makes good sense.

What still does not make good sense is the mutability of `x_arg` within the function itself. The presenter in the video I just watched refused to use the same variable name because of the claim of immutability.

So—if I follow your reasoning, my expectation would be a compiler failure at compile time (best) or at runtime (worst). However, I get no failure at all.

Am I seeing this right?

Comment: This is exactly the same thing : the variable x_arg gets re bound within the scope of the function :)